# Log4jdbc-log4j2 to log OracleTypes.CURSOR

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I'm using Log4jdbc-log4j2 to log database activity ,everything was logging as expected but it makes it impossible to log oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.

Can some one please advise on how to log this OracleTypes.CURSOR resultset in log files?

Comment: Please elaborate your question and show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: below is the pseudo code----   CallableStatement callableStatement =connectionSpy.prepareCall("{call schema.package.get_procs (?)}".toUpperCase()); 
   
      callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1,OracleTypes.CURSOR);
      callableStatement.executeQuery();
   ResultSet resultSet =(ResultSet) callableStatement.getObject(1);

Comment: LOG O/P---- --- log o/p   CallableStatement.executeQuery() returned net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.ResultSetSpy@2b38b5c6  
2015-06-09 22:22:39 audit [DEBUG] 2. CallableStatement.getObject(1) returned oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl@1825f055  
2015-06-09 22:22:39 audit [DEBUG] 2. CallableStatement.close() returned   
2015-06-09 22:22:39 audit [DEBUG] 1. Connection.close() returned   .........resultset table not logged